# iphone app was terminate when splash screen loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I built my app on a simulator the app launches normally.  But I build with Adhoc distribution and install to iPhone, The app can launch and show a splash screen, and then it was terminate.

I add a break point in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {}.
```

The break point can't trap.

Please tell the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Check console and debugger logs. Post what you find here and I'm sure someone will help you interpret the error.

Comment: I formatted the code but I don't know Objective-C.  Could someone please correct any syntax errors?  I'm particularly suspect of that period at the end.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's likely to be a problem with provisioning profiles. You can use Settings -> General -> Profiles to check that your adhoc certificate (note: it's separate from your development certificate) is installed and hasn't expired. Attempting to launch an application without the correct provisioning profile will cause exactly the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Tommy, provisioning profile related. Go through all the steps getting your app ready for adhoc - [this O'Reilly guide](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1434-how-to-prepare-an-iphone-app-for-ad-hoc-distribution/) is useful, otherwise the Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW1) are the first place to look.

Certainly, before building your application, open the app's plist file and make sure the Bundle Identifier in your Info.plist file matches the one used to create the ad hoc mobile provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you built on iPhone using Ad Hoc distribution, I assume you sent your mobileprovision file and app bundle to the test end user, who installed via iTunes.  If this is the case, you can check the Crash logs that should be here:

Windows:
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice

Mac:
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice

Answer (score 0):

Do you do any large downloads (or init that takes several seconds) during startup?
If your app doesn't start fast enough the OS will kill it.